# Nginx status code metrics under heavy load

Tags: nginx, scalability

I have an Elasticsearch Logstash Kibana stack to monitor my nginx server. Each nginx log is taken, parsed, stored and aggregated on demand. As I have a high traffic, this stack is very heavy to maintain.

I am looking for a throughput meter of nginx response codes to print every second the sum of status code reponse by category (2xx, 3xx, 4xx, 5xx). Where should I look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few options:

- Status module, which, as @VBart mentioned, is available for commercial subscribers only http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_status_module.html#data
- Open sources alternatives, i.e **nginx-sla**:
  https://github.com/goldenclone/nginx-sla/blob/master/README.en.md

  I've seen **nginx-sla** in production on nginx instances under very high load.
  Not sure whether it's compatible with the latest versions though
- Come up with your own solution. For example, route 4xx  / 5xx / whatever error groups to dedicated logs, aggregate them locally on nginx's boxes and either pick up by a local agent (i.e. zabbix_agent if you have zabbix) or send elsewhere depending on your stack. Notice you can just dump aggregated metrics (wc -l) and then figure out the dynamics in your tool of choice

Answer (score 0):

The status module of nginx plus has such feature:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_status_module.html#data